# showing text in android app

Tags: java, android, text

i have two different .java files and I want to show my received data into other files textview. Or is there a other way to view this directly? I'm making a push message app and i got stuck at this part:

```
public void publishArrived(String topicName, byte[] payload, int qos, boolean retained) {
        // Show a notification
        String s = new String(payload);
        showNotification(s);    
        //  ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.message_text)).setText(messageValue);
        messageValue = s;
        log("Got message: " + s);
    }
```

This doesn't work, because the  setContentView(R.layout.main); is requested in an other file. How does this work?

```
 ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.message_text)).setText(messageValue);
```

How should I look at this? It would be logical to

Comment: You should use the context of your activity in your function if possible

Comment: yes, i was thinking to use concole.readstring, but its not working. I've found bufferedReader, but i cannot get that working neither.

Comment: I guess you Push is from C2DM, so you may send a broadcast from this class, to your running activity with a broadcast listener, and put this String in extra of your Broadcast Intent.

Comment: https://github.com/tokudu/AndroidPushNotificationsDemo no it's the tokodu one. How do i broadcast this?

Comment: can't find your file, where is publishArrived(...) ?

Answer (score 1):

Start activity from service method PublishArrived as

```
    String messageValue = s;

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);     
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
    intent.putExtra("message", messageValue);
    startActivity(intent);
```

and in onCreate() of SecondActivity get this message & show in view as

```
    String messageValue = getIntent().getStringExtra("message");
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.message_text)).setText(messageValue);
```

You can also use broadcast receiver as suggested above.